# GCC (MinGW) and WINAPI calls on Windows 32 bits

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

When I assemble a file using GCC tools (from MinGW package), calls to WINAPI functions from system DLLs have this form:

```
        call label
        ...
        ret
label:  jmp dword [ExitProcess]
```

Instead of:

```
        call dword [ExitProcess]
        ...
        ret
```

How can I force GCC to call directly idata section pointers instead of generating that extra code?

Comment: What compiler options did you use for your build?

Comment: I compiled it using: as -o main.o main.S -lkernel32 -luser32 & ld -o main.exe main.o

Comment: Neither of those commands are GCC. I suggest you reformulate your question. What does the assembler source code look like? What output are you looking at? What's the real problem here? What versions number do the tools report?

Comment: Then: gcc -o main.exe main.S. Same result. Code? Any code that calls a function from a Windows DLL.

Comment: No solutions? It is silly that GCC needs to generate extra code to do a simple indirect call...

Comment: I asked you to post your source code and you ignored me ..... also, GCC doesn't do anything to assembler files, so it must be an assembler or linker thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

If you want (this will throw a segment fault)

```
call *_MessageBoxA@16
```

do this instead

```
call *__imp__MessageBoxA@16
```

and you will get an indirect call without extra useless code.